# How to change check in policy behaviour with tfs power tools 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, workitem, tfs-power-tools, checkin-policy

trouble again with Team Foundation Server Power Tools 2012. I just installed VS2012 and the power tools. We use check in policies. My problem: when I associate a ticket with a check in (as my policy demands), **the ticket is set to 'resolved'**. I don't want this behaviour, does anybody know how to change it?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the process editor included in power tools to make that change.

Here is a blog post detailing several ways to make this change:

[Changing the default Check-In Option](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Changing-the-Default-CheckIn-Option-to-Associate-in-TFS-2012.aspx)

Comment: One up for the link, very interesting. But I don't really like what I read there...

Comment: Ok, I'll rate this as answer. Really seems an issue, many people complaining. See this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3629326e-a858-41a7-bafa-f5e4233a7bba/vs-2012-checkin-work-item-association-type-is-not-defaulted-to-associate

Answer (score 0):

Check the WITD of the ticket (work item).

The XML will have Action="Check-in" under the transition "Active" To "resolved". Remove this action. That's it.

Comment: I fear don't have access to the WITD. I guess you need access to the server?